# Get a correct after_stat for geom_bar when also implicitly grouping by level of a variable (using fill)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a somewhat unique situation. I've provided a bit of sample data.

```
s <- data.frame( x = 
    rep(c("Black", "Blue","Brown","Green", 
    "Grey", "Orange", "Purple", "Red", "White", 
    "Yellow"),
    c(90, 40, 16, 23, 1, 71, 32, 43, 28, 5)) )
s$x <- factor(s$x)
```

One might imagine that, because the actual data being counted and graphed are colours, something like the following could be handy.

```
 ggplot(s, aes(x = x, fill = x)) + 
      scale_fill_manual(values = levels(s$x)) + 
      geom_bar()
```

My issue is that I'd like the output in proportions of the total numbers here instead of counts. However, I can't seem to get it to work correctly with `geom_bar`. I'm well aware that I could make a dataset containing the proportions and use `geom_col`. But I'm trying to find a solution sticking with `geom_bar`.

Note that putting something like `y = after_stat(prop)` in the `geom_bar` call does not solve the problem, even though one should think that ti would.

Comment: I agree with the other reviewers in that this is a programming question and as such, StackOverflow is a better outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**
In your `geom_bar()`, just include `y = aes( after_stat(count)  / sum(after_stat(count)) )`.

You may also want your y-axis showing percentage.You can replace the current scale with `scale_y_continues(labels=percent)`.

Comment: Thanks, this does work and it's interesting that the after_stat(prop) doesn't work even though it should be the same thing.